# Control the use of .each()

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a few links:

```
<a class="high_res_link" href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/websterk3/6637215599/">
<a class="high_res_link" href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/44108990@N08/4416648216/">
<a class="high_res_link no_pop" href="http://oix.tumblr.com/image/72876442290">
…
```

I am wanting to be able to alert each href individually. Instead of currently them all  alerting one by one. By for example going `alert(href[1])` and it only alerting: `http://www.flickr.com/photos/websterk3/6637215599/sizes/o/` *(The first link)*

```
$('.high_res_link').each(function(){
var href = $(this).attr('href');
href = href+"sizes/o/";
alert(href);
});
```

---

And I am also looking to prevent anything with the class `no_pop` because it links to tumblr instead of flickr. Can you make a rule for the variable `href` so that it can't contain the string `tumblr` maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a mix of both @still_learning and @Alex Shilman's answers

```
 var href = [];
$('.high_res_link').not('.no_pop').each(function(){
  var h = $(this).attr('href') + "sizes/o/";
  href.push(h);
});

alert(href[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

each() will do just that, iterate through each link. You want to alert when a specific link is clicked. The click function will be called when an element of class `.high_res_link` but not of class `.no_pop` is clicked. The `this` keyword refers to the element that triggered the function, so it will display the corresponding alert depending on which link was clicked.

```
   $('.high_res_link').not('.no_pop').click(function(e){
       var href = $(this).attr('href');
       href = href+"sizes/o/";
       alert(href);
       e.preventDefault();
   });
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Sionnach733/y2uGR/2/)

Comment: What about if I wanted the second `<a>` tag?

Comment: this should work, is there an error? Check the jsfiddle example

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
$(function(){
 $('.high_res_link').not('.no_pop').click(function(e){
   var href = $(this).attr('href');
   href = href+"sizes/o/";
   alert(href);
   e.preventDefault();
 });
});
```

HTML:

```
 <a class="high_res_link" href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/websterk3/6637215599/">
 link1</a>
 <a class="high_res_link" href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/44108990@N08/4416648216/">
  link2</a>
 <a class="high_res_link no_pop" href="http://oix.tumblr.com/image/72876442290">
 link3</a>
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/3Vycs/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$('.high_res_link').not('.no_pop').each(function(){
var href = $(this).attr('href');
href = href+"sizes/o/";
alert(href);
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsbin.com/AjOhUcIn/1/edit)**

Answer (score 0):

Use an additional array:

```
var href = [];
$('.high_res_link :not(.no_pop)').each(function(){
  var h = $(this).attr('href') + "sizes/o/";
  href.push(h);
});

alert(href[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use function in the click event of each link as below

```
$(function(){
 $('.high_res_link').click(function(){
   var href = $(this).attr('href');
   href = href+"sizes/o/";
   alert(href);
 });
});
```

If you want to alert for specific link. for example if you want to alert for second link,use the below coding

```
 $(function(){
     $('.high_res_link').eq(1).click(function(){
       var href = $(this).attr('href');
       href = href+"sizes/o/";
       alert(href);
     });
    });
```

Comment: `.hasClass` returns a boolean value!